# how to run the cronjob for particular time?

Tags: shell, cron, jobs

I am trying to run at specific time to run the job , but its not running. But if i run for every 5 minutes. I can see the results

```
08 05 * * * /bin/sh -c /ngs/app/b2bwebd/data/share/bin/webmethodsBackup.sh
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh -c /ngs/app/b2bwebd/data/share/bin/webmethodsBackup.sh
```

Could you please guide to solve the above concern.

Comment: what is the schedule that you want and where do you want to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command `crontab -e` in linux to get into the crontab configuration. Write on the bottom of the file the following line with the schedule `47 14 * * *`. This will execute at minute 47 of hour 14. If you want to create another schedule use this site https://crontab.guru/ that demonstrates when it will be schedules.

This is one example of what you can write on the crontab schedule. It will write `hello at XXXX` at the file `/home/your-user/crontab.out`

```
47 14 * * * echo "hello at XXXX" > ~/crontab.out
```